# How to check existence of user-define table type in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, user-defined-types

I have a user-defined table type. I want to check it's existence before editing in a patch using `OBJECT_ID(name, type)` function.

What `type` from the [enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx) should be passed for user-defined table types?

`N'U'` like for user defined table doesn't work, i.e. `IF OBJECT_ID(N'MyType', N'U') IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 242, accepted):

You can look in sys.types or use TYPE_ID:

```
IF TYPE_ID(N'MyType') IS NULL ...
```

Just a precaution: using type_id won't verify that the type is a ***table*** type--just that a type by that name exists.  Otherwise gbn's query is probably better.

Comment: I was naively trying to do `IF OBJECT_ID(N'MyType', 'TT') IS NULL` with no success, but your solution worked.

Comment: The 'TT' enumeration only works in sql server 2012 or later (as i just found out)

Comment: @Iain It still doesn't, actually. You can't use OBJECT_ID to search for a table type by name -- check out `SELECT name FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'TT'`

Comment: what is the use of N before 'MyType'?

Comment: @NishantKumar The `N` prefix makes the string literal a Unicode string.

Answer (score 140):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.types WHERE is_table_type = 1 AND name = 'MyType')
    --stuff
```

[sys.types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188021.aspx)... they aren't in [sys.objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx) under their normal name

Update, Mar 2013

You can use [TYPE_ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181628.aspx) too

Comment: I believe your second comment is inaccurate. If I'm not mistaken, User-Defined Types are indeed schema-scoped (The `Schema_ID` is in fact one of the attributes in the [sys.types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188021.aspx) table you linked to; this is why they can be referenced as [dbo].[myUDType]). Nevertheless, you are correct that UD types are not listed in sys.objects, and therefore not accessible by OBJECT_ID(). (For whatever reason, sys.objects isn't an exhaustive list of schema-scoped objects.)

Comment: @kmote - They are not listed in `sys.objects` directly but [there is a row there for each of these](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20483910/73226)

Answer (score 21):

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.types WHERE name = 'Person' AND is_table_type = 1 AND schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('VAB'))
DROP TYPE VAB.Person;
go
CREATE TYPE VAB.Person AS TABLE
(    PersonID               INT
    ,FirstName              VARCHAR(255)
    ,MiddleName             VARCHAR(255)
    ,LastName               VARCHAR(255)
    ,PreferredName          VARCHAR(255)
);
```

Comment: I think this is a more complete answer since it checks schema as well.

Comment: Where does the value for `schema_id` come from? (since it isn't in the OP)

Answer (score 7):

Following examples work for me, please note "is_user_defined" NOT "is_table_type"

```
IF TYPE_ID(N'idType') IS NULL
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[idType] FROM Bigint NOT NULL
go

IF not EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.types WHERE is_user_defined = 1 AND name = 'idType')
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[idType] FROM Bigint NOT NULL
go
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use also system table_types view

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT *
           FROM   [sys].[table_types]
           WHERE  user_type_id = Type_id(N'[dbo].[UdTableType]'))
  BEGIN
      PRINT 'EXISTS'
  END
```