# SQL Server create User-Defined Table Types with schema not working properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, schema, user-defined-types

I'm creating User-Defined Table Types on SQL Server 2008R2/2012 with this statement:

```
CREATE TYPE [MySchemaName].[MyUserTableType] 
   As Table ( [Id] varchar(20) NOT NULL );
```

This works as intended.

I also got a stored procedure which deletes all associated object to a given Schema.
This is where my User-Defined Table Types are not working properly. I am expecting
that those Types are created with an associated schema.

If i try to drop the schema, it will complain that the schema is associated with my User-Defined Table Type. Hence it will not be deleted.

But if i query all objects in my DB which are TYPE_TABLE it tells me that my Table types do not belong to my schema. They belong to the schema 'sys'

```
SELECT name, schema_id, type_desc 
FROM [TESTDB].SYS.OBJECTS 
WHERE type_desc = 'TYPE_TABLE';

SELECT * FROM sys.schemas;
```

Any idea why?

Here is a screenshot from my output
[image]

Comment: It is my understanding that User Defined Types are always assigned to the "SYS" schema so this is the expected behaviour. User Defined Schemas can be assigned to Functions, Procedures, Tables and Triggers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of looking in `sys.objects` for these you should look in `sys.types` or `sys.table_types` (which additionally exposes the `type_table_object_id`).

```
SELECT name,
       schema_id /*Will be the "test" schema id*/
FROM   sys.types
WHERE  is_table_type = 1
       AND name = 'MyUserTableType'
```

When you create a user defined type it adds a row to `sys.sysscalartypes` with the user supplied schema and name and a row to `sys.sysschobjs` with a system generated name in the `sys` schema. The system generated name is created by concatenating `TT_` + FriendlyName + `_` + Hex version of object id.

The two entities are related together via `sys.syssingleobjrefs`

```
/*This query only works via the DAC*/
SELECT so.id AS object_id,
       st.id AS user_type_id,
       *
FROM   sys.sysschobjs so
       JOIN sys.syssingleobjrefs sor
         ON sor.indepid = so.id
       JOIN sys.sysscalartypes st
         ON st.id = sor.depid
WHERE  st.name = 'MyUserTableType'
```