# T-SQL DROP TYPE IF EXISTS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm currently working on a script in T-SQL in SQL Server 2014.

I need to drop a user-defined table type, but only if it exists, and create it again after the delete/drop type.

I did some research on the web and found a solution, which does, unfortunately, not work at all.

My current script looks like this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('MySchema.tProjectType', 'U') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TYPE [MySchema].[tProjectType];

CREATE TYPE [MySchema].[tProjectType] AS TABLE
    (
        Id INT
        , IsPrivate BIT
        , IsPublic BIT
    );
```

My error message:

> The type 'MySchema.tProjectType' already exists, or you do not have permission to create it.

Do you know how to successfully check if a user defined table type exists before I can delete it in SQL Server 2014?

Comment: Table types aren't objects -- specifically, they aren't *tables*. Use `TYPE_ID` instead.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Please try this, use **type_id** instead of **object_id**

```
IF type_id('[MySchema].[tProjectType]') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TYPE [MySchema].[tProjectType];


CREATE TYPE [MySchema].[tProjectType] AS TABLE
    (
        Id INT
        , IsPrivate BIT
        , IsPublic BIT
    );
```

Comment: SQL Server 2016 SP1 onward, you can now simply use DROP TYPE IF EXISTS ...   according to this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-type-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 2):

Use [TYPE_ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/type-id-transact-sql)

Or query [sys.table_types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-table-types-transact-sql)

Comment: `OBJECT_ID` will not work. There is a `TT` object backing every table type, but it has a system-generated name.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I thought they'd fixed this since https://stackoverflow.com/a/2495240/27535

Comment: Verified explicitly that this does not work on SQL Server 2016 SP1 CU. Neither `OBJECT_ID('x')` nor `OBJECT_ID('x', 'TT')` will return results for a table type `x`. The backing internal table will have a name like `TT_x_12345678`. I don't think you're really supposed to do anything with it; it's there for completeness (along with any constraints), but the table isn't really the type.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.types WHERE is_table_type = 1 AND name ='tProjectType') 
    Begin
         DROP TYPE [tProjectType];
         CREATE TYPE [tProjectType] AS TABLE
            (
                 Id INT
                , IsPrivate BIT
                , IsPublic BIT
            );
        END
```

Before Droping table type check that table type is using in any stored procedures otherwise it will raise error like table Type is having dependencies